# Browse by category returning no elements

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am trying the get the products displayed for a category.  I got this error message:  Sequence contains no elements.    I got a table product and a table category.  Each product is identified to a category.

HomeController.cs

```
      public ActionResult Browse(string nomCategorie)
    {
        var categorieModel =  db.Categories.Include("Produits")   <== the error happened here
            .Single(g => g.NomCategorie == nomCategorie);

        return View(categorieModel);
    }
```

Browse.cshtml

```
 @model MVCWebStore.Models.Categorie

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Browse";
 }

 <h2>Browse Categorie: @Model.NomCategorie</h2>
 <ul>
     @foreach (var produit in Model.Produits)
     {
         <li>
             @produit.Description
         </li>
     }
 </ul>
```

Produit.cs

```
 namespace MVCWebStore.Models
 {
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;

     public partial class Produit
     {
         public Produit()
         {
             this.ItemPaniers = new HashSet<ItemPanier>();
         }

         public int IdProduit { get; set; }
         public int IdCategorie { get; set; }
         public string NomProduit { get; set; }
         public string Description { get; set; }
         public double Prix { get; set; }
         public int Quantite { get; set; }

         public virtual Categorie Categorie { get; set; }
         public virtual ICollection<ItemPanier> ItemPaniers { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

categorie.cs
     namespace MVCWebStore.Models 
     {
         using System;
         using System.Collections.Generic;

```
     public partial class Categorie
     {
         public Categorie()
         {
             this.Produits = new HashSet<Produit>();
         }

         public int IdCategorie { get; set; }
         public string NomCategorie { get; set; }

         public virtual ICollection<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

Comment: paste the model for `Categories` and `Produits` please.

Comment: have you tried changing Single to FirstorDefault?

Comment: @user3311522  I got further but it fail in the browse with the same error message  at this line <h2>Browse Categorie: @Model.NomCategorie</h2>

Comment: @user3311522  sorry the error message is  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: seems to be the @model.NomCategorie it stopped there

Comment: is the tables correctly created?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48523/discussion-between-user3127986-and-user3311522)

Comment: cant right now unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance your `datacontext` is not getting loaded correctly.
Might be something wrong with `connectionsting`. make sure the `datacontext` is not null.

If the problem is not with that, chances are tables are not created/linked correctly.

Also EF is weird around the children data a bit. definitely not the greatest framework.